# Does erlang:disconnect_node/2 immediately stop queued messages?

Tags: erlang

If I sent a lot of messages to a remote node and immediately call `erlang:disconnect_node/2` to drop the connection, is there a chance some messages don't get through the wire? In other words, does that method perform a brutal disconnection, regardless of waiting messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even with two local nodes!

**Setup**: I got a node `a@super`, on witch a dummy receive-print loop runs, registered with `a`. On another node, I run

```
(b@super)1> [{a, a@super} ! X || X <- lists:seq(0,10000)], erlang:disconnect_node(a@super).
```

That is, many messages, and then a brutal disconnection.

**Result**: the receiver printed the full 10001 messages only once over 10 runs.

So, you definitely do not have any guarantee the receiver got all the messages. You should use another technique (novice at erlang, sorry), or use an ack message before the disconnect.